# What is the minimal girth of a two-generator cayley graph for Alt(n) in which the girth relator is not a proper power?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

First, a definition: a girth relator for a Cayley graph is a word that you get by reading the edge labels along a shortest loop. The girth relator is not usually unique, though it is often unique up to cyclic conjugating. Now the question: what is the smallest girth that a Cayley graph of the alternating group Alt(n) can have, given that no girth relator is a proper power? Without the restriction on the girth relator, the answer is 2, since you can always take one of the generators to be of order 2. If there are more than two generators, two of them may commute, giving a girth relator of length 4, the commutator, which is not a proper power. However, in the two-generator case, with the restriction on the girth relator, it is not clear that there is a universal upper bound, the answer might depend on n. None the less, I suspect the answer is 6. Any relator on two generators with length less than 6 either implies solvability of the group, or implies that one of the generators has small order. The relator aabABB (where capitals are inverses) is the smallest candidate for being a girth relator for all large Alt(n) without being a power.